# How do I choose between multiple implementations of the same interface with Autofac?

Tags: c#, autofac

The WebApi I am using, can be consumed by different Credentials.
The line below is where I am trying to resolve within `ICustomerWebApi` registration.

```cs
b.ResolveKeyed<ICredentialProvider>("KeyA")
 .ServiceClientCredentials
```

But sometimes, it might need to use the below instead, depending on where the `ICustomerWebApi` is being used.

```cs
b.ResolveKeyed<ICredentialProvider>("KeyB")
 .ServiceClientCredentials
```

Is there a solution to this problem?

```cs
builder.RegisterType<CredentialProvider>()
       .Keyed<ICredentialProvider>("KeyA")
       .InstancePerRequest();

builder.Register(b =>
  {
    var result = new CustomerWebApi(
                   new Uri("http://sales.microsoft.com/api"),
                   b.ResolveKeyed<ICredentialProvider>("KeyA").ServiceClientCredentials);
    return result;   
  }).As<ICustomerWebApi>();
```

Comment: In order to answer the question accurately we need more info. Do you have the logic of when to make the decision at registration time or only at resolution time? [Have you read the FAQ on this topic which may give you ideas?](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq/select-by-context.html)

Comment: The different credentials to be used, will be decided at resolution time within constructor.

Comment: Within _which_ constructor? The consumer? How does the decision get made? Same way every time? Different every time? I hate to be pedantic, but it does take a lot of time to write up a good answer with working code examples (think an hour or two sometimes). Providing as much information as you can up front with a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is super important for you to get the right answer that will work for you, especially since this isn't a discussion forum; it's more an "ask a complete question, get a complete answer" sort of thing.

Comment: Appreciate that. I will try my best to include as much info as possible.

The reason why I need to use different credentials, is because sometimes an "Admin" account credential needs to be used to perform administration tasks.

Within a controller e.g AdminController(), it needs to use the Admin credentials, where as a normal controller, CustomerController() will just use the standard credentials.

The decision is set, and will not change.